# Find the maximum magnitude and print it

Tags: shell

I have a set of values as shown below.

```
-4.904045E+04   3.972944E+04
-1.205839E+05   3.662380E+04
-1.950760E+04   1.020331E+01
-1.128968E-01   1.129738E+05
-8.031810E+01   1.466682E+05
-4.914462E+04   2.353826E+03
-4.020837E+04   3.524823E+01
-3.058178E+03   1.234481E+04
```

I would like to find the maximum magnitude of the two and print the result with the original sign (nagative or positive).

Ex: I need the result like this:

```
-4.904045E+04
-1.205839E+05
-1.950760E+04
1.129738E+05
1.466682E+05
-4.914462E+04
-4.020837E+04
1.234481E+04
```

Please let me know the code for performing this. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does this have to do with *nix and what have you tried?

Comment: @jordanm, it's tagged /shell-script, so Mark is asking for a solution using a Unix shell script. This kind of question is very common here

Answer (score 2):

If `$1`  is always negative and `$2` always positive:

```
awk '{print(-$1>$2?$1:$2)}' < your-file
```

If not:

```
awk 'function abs(x) {return (x<0?-x:x)}
     {print(abs($1)>abs($2)?$1:$2)}' < your-file
```

Answer (score 2):

And here's a Perl one:

```
perl -alne 'abs($F[0])>abs($F[1]) ? print $F[0] : print $F[1]' < file
```

Flags:

- `-e` : give a script in the command line
- `-n` : run the script given by `e` on each line of the input file
- `-a` : splits each line at white space into the array `@F`
- `-l` : automatically adds a new line (`\n`) to each `print`.